# Reduce stair support in kitchen

Tags: stairs, joinery

I've been living with this box in my kitchen for a year since I've moved in and I hate it. I thought I would be able to reduce it for a better kitchen design.

However now I've removed it I want to reduce the actual stair support and lower the ceiling 4-5 inches.

Looking at these photos can anybody recommend the best way to do it?

[image: Box removed]

A house nearby has had the ceiling lowered slight to about 8ft with no disruption to the stairs, this was done prior to them moving in though so unawares to how its done.

I really dislike it, it’s making kitchen designs unattractive so I want it out

Comment: I only see one photo, and I have to turn my head sideways to make any sense of it. If you have any more or want to rotate this one, tap the 'edit' link.

Comment: What is the existing ceiling height?

Comment: Just a comment - too little information to fully answer (e.g., ceiling height). But I would generally keep the ceiling height overall as-is - unless a ceiling is really high (e.g., > 10'), generally the room will seem bigger with a taller ceiling without costing that much extra in HVAC. I would box right up to the stair support but **not** try to change the stairs - too much work for very little benefit.

Comment: We'd have to at least know what the stairs are for, why they're so shallow in slope, and how far into the finished area above you're willing to go to reconfigure. The question is unanswerable as it is.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the stairs go around a corner, maybe with a small landing.  With the masonry wall, it looks like an older home that's had the kitchen redone.  Guessing at the risers being 6-7" tall, it protrudes about 12-14" down into the kitchen ceiling.  Reframing those stairs would be a good sized undertaking. Would it be worth the effort to tear out the stairs, rebuild them, fix the walls around the stairs, and try to match existing trim just to add access to the space above the kitchen cabinets and get a flat kitchen ceiling?

Maybe you could build in shelving, add other cabinets, or replace the existing with taller ones that go to the ceiling to simply hide the stairs.

Comment: It’s worth it for me mate, I need it gone, can’t spend ££££ on a kitchen i hate because of that monstrous thing. You’re correct it’s a small landing onto another landing, it’s been done in the same house across the street but done before a friend moved in, the stairs look the same.

Comment: Such a change will touch 2-3 rooms, possibly more. That's more involved than we can comment on from a single picture. I suggest you talk to a few different contractors, get multiple bids, and see what else will be involved with this change (e.g. plumbing, electrical, structural). These will need to be evaluated by somebody coming onsite to look. Good luck!